# Copy from Ubuntu VM terminal into clipboard and paste to Windows without using mouse

Tags: linux, clipboard

I have this nice alias which works well within my Ubuntu when I need to copy some terminal output right into my clipboard:

```
alias xclip='xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard'
```

Now something like `cat myfile | xclip` and I have output in the clipboard ready to be pasted within Ubuntu, which is really handy.

However, this does not work if I want to paste into my Windows 10 host (I am using Ubuntu VM). I always select and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but I would love to be able to copy command output straight into clipboard just like selecting and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Is there similar thing to `xclip` where I can copy/paste from Ubuntu to Windows 10 without mouse selection?

Comment: Take a look at program `xcutsel`. Linux has more than one clipboard, and vmware/virtualbox copy automatically only one.

Answer (score 2):

Using the primary clipboard as target works for me (Ubuntu). I can paste the string into my VMware host (provided that clipboard sharing is configured correctly):

`echo hello | xclip -selection p`

or shorter:

`echo hello | xclip -i`

Comment: i tried this and the mouse selected (i.e. copied into the clip board in linux vm) did not get to shared on windows.

Comment: Both primary (-p) and clipboard (-c) don't work for me for pasting to windows reliably. Just sometimes when I first do `xclip -selection primary` then `xclip -selection secondary` pasting to windows works. When I use `xclip -selection primary` I can't even past it to other programs in the Ubuntu VW. Very strange behavior.

Comment: This actually hinted me in the right direction. The solution that then worked for me, was this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/69134/147659